# Why is MDI child form's Activate event not working?

Tags: vb.net, mdi

I am creating a Windows application using VB.NET and SQL Server. My VB project contains a `mdiform` and 5 `mdichild` forms. `frmStudmaster` is one of the child forms.

In this form I want to display all the details of a particular student. The form `frmstudent` contains a `searchrollNo` button. So to get student roll number I want to use a search form. The search form is not mdichild.

When I click the `searchRollno` button, the search form is opened and displays all student roll numbers from the SQL Server table. When I select a rollnumber the search form closed, `rollnumber` passes to `frmStudentmaster`'s `rollnotextbox` and the search form is closed. My problem is that in the closing event of the search form, I have written code to activate `frmstudentmaster`. But when I close the search form, the control goes to `mdiform` and `frmstudent` master is not activated.

Comment: Code would probably be helpful. Without it, we cannot do much.

Comment: Do you make sure you activate `frmstudentmaster` *before* you close the search form?